# I am getting TypeError is not a function in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

I have a login route but whenever it's giving me a typeError not a function. I have checked the code too many times but still can't get why it's giving me this error:

Here's the code:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!email || !password) {
      return res.status(400).send("Please provide an email and password");
    }

    const user = await User.find({ email });

    if (!user) return res.status(401).send("User not found");
    const isMatch = await user.checkHashedPassword(password);
    if (!isMatch) return res.status(401).send("Invalid credentials");
    sendTokenResponse(user, 200, res);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
  }
});
```

The error I get is that user.checkHashedPassword is not a function.

Here's the checkHashedPassword method in userSchema:

```
userSchema.methods.checkHashedPassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
};
```

Here's the complete error that I get:

```
TypeError: user.checkHashedPassword is not a function
    at D:\pythonprogs\todoapp\routes\users.js:46:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I have checked the spellings and everything even changed the function name to see if it works but don't know why it's giving this error. Please help

Comment: @Adil Khalil That doesn't make sense since there's another userSchema method that I am using and it works. Please note that the userSchema is a mongoose Schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is you are using find() method instead of findOne().

find() returns  array of collections not object. try this:

```
const isMatch = await user[0].checkHashedPassword(password)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. The reason I was using find because in my schema, email was set to be unique so there could only be one email in db. But, thanks again. You saved my day

Comment: @ohnope . mongo find behavior is return array. It doesn't care about your result is one object or array of objects. So there is a reason for having find() method and find one() method.